# Missing Header In Kernel Compile ... but Header is Installed

Tags: compilation, header, linux-kernel

I am having a strange problem compiling a new kernel for a board I'm using...

I simply have to call a ./makeall.sh script to compile everything, so I'm not in control of flags.  A coworker has already built this successfully.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit.

The problem is:

```
In file included from base.h:26,
             from mod_flv_streaming.c:1:
keyvalue.h:56: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
keyvalue.h:61: warning: struct has no members
```

I see this often, and another line complains about not finding /usr/include/pcre.h

---

I have the following lilbraries installed, and pcre.h does exist in /usr/include:

- libpcre3-dev
- libpcre++-dev
- libpcrecpp0

Of course the runtimes are also installed (remove the -dev)

Any advice? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to a weird situation where Ubuntu 10.04 had:

```
/bin/sh -> /bin/dash
```

linking

```
/bin/sh -> /bin/bash
```

led to a successful compile.